# How do I enable hyperthreading in a Intel Xeon E5-2407?

Tags: virtualization, cpu

We have the following CPU that supports hyper-threading. Though Ubuntu doesn't recognize that each core supports 4 threads.

Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2407
http://ark.intel.com/products/64614/

The server is a Dell PowerEdge R320
http://www.dell.com/support/Manuals/us/en/19/product/poweredge-r320

The results of lscpu is
lscpu

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                2
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
CPU socket(s):         1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Stepping:              10
CPU MHz:               800.000
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              6144K
```

I've gone thru and checked the BIOS and I enabled all the features related to virtualization and logical CPUs.

Any ideas?

cpufreq is not being run as asked below

sudo cpufreq-info 
cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 1:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 2:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 3:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.

Comment: are you using any cpufreq utils ?, it seems your processor is in conservative mode .....and your 6 cores are offline

Comment: try lscpu with Ubuntu 13.04 live cd.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel Xeon E5-2407 **does not** have Hyper-threading. Refer to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#Xeon_E5-2xxx_.28dual-processor.29). The Intel page you link to also lists the CPU has having only threads across 4 cores.

Comment: Yes this is correct. The link that you gave, @user151932, specifically said it doesn't support hyperthreading.  http://ark.intel.com/products/64614/#HyperThreading

Answer (score -1):

11.10 is really old. Give 12.04 a try at least (if you want LTS... which you probably do.)
It should see all the cores. If it doesn't, report this as a bug.

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: I ran the 12.04 LiveCd, still the threads per core sees only 1 thread

Comment: @user151932: Simple. Open up "**top**" in a terminal, and press "**1**". It will show you how many CPUs you have. Or **cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep CPU**